# capturing stdout from RScript via C#

Tags: c#, r, stdout, rscript

I'm trying to run an R script utilizing the RScript.exe located in the \bin\ directory of an R installation.  Running RScript from the windows command line writes results to the screen.  When I try to replicate in C# using the System.Diagnostics.Process(), the output seems to be missing.

For a simple example, I'm going to ignore my actual r code, and just try to read version information from RScript.exe.  When run from the cmd prompt:

```
rscript --version
```

I see on the screen

```
R scripting front-end version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
```

When I do the same in this c# code, nothing is captured.

```
StringBuilder outputBuilder = new StringBuilder();

System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

proc.StartInfo.FileName = "rscript";
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
proc.StartInfo.ErrorDialog = false;
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "--version";
proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

proc.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler
(
    delegate(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        outputBuilder.Append(e.Data);
    }
);
proc.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler
(
    delegate(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        outputBuilder.Append(e.Data);
    }
);

proc.Start();
proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
proc.BeginErrorReadLine();

proc.WaitForExit();
string allOutput = outputBuilder.ToString();
```

It seems like this should be very simple, but despite looking at many examples of capturing stdout from c#, I'm still stumped.

Comment: My latest guess is that RScript doesn't write to stdout when launched via `System.Diagnostics.Process()`.  I have no idea why that'd be the case though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up working for me, I'm not sure exactly what the problem was as it looks nearly identical to the original.

```
public void test()

    string exe = @"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.5.2\bin\x64\Rscript.exe";

    System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
    psi.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(exe);
    psi.Arguments = "--version";
    psi.FileName = exe;

    psi.UseShellExecute = false;
    psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
    psi.CreateNoWindow = true;

    proc.StartInfo = psi;

    proc.ErrorDataReceived += consoleDataReceived;
    proc.OutputDataReceived += consoleDataReceived;
    proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    proc.Start();
    proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
    proc.BeginErrorReadLine();

    while (!proc.HasExited)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }

    //this flushes the rest of the messages out.
    proc.WaitForExit();
}

public void consoleDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    string strMessage = e.Data;
    Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try as said below.

Use `Process.StandardOutput` property. (You already set `RedirectStandardOutput` to true).

This returns a `StreamReader` which can be used to read the standard output stream of the application.

ex:
after starting the process..

```
string output = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

Look into below link for more details.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput(v=vs.110).aspx

You have to call before `WaitForExit()`. The above link explains most of the consequences.

Comment: Sorry, the string is still empty, even after those changes.

Comment: Did you remove the asynchronous calls BeginOutputReadLine();??

Comment: Yep, commented out all of the event handlers too.